# How to insert a complex dynamic nested json into bigquery using java

Tags: java, json, google-bigquery

I am using the JSON that is coming from the xAPI system and the JSON looks similar to the one available in the [link](https://github.com/adlnet/xAPI-Spec/blob/master/xAPI-About.md#Appendix1B%20And%20I%20need%20to%20insert%20into%20this%20json) into BigQuery where in the schema of the BigQuery is slightly altered.

Example: In the JSON for the child element `verb`

```json
"verb":{  
    "id":"http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/failed",
    "display":{  
      "en-US":"failed"
    }
  }
```

The schema is like below:

```
verb                        RECORD  NULLABLE    
verb.id                     STRING  NULLABLE    
verb.display                RECORD  REPEATED    
verb.display.stringValue    STRING  NULLABLE    
verb.display.languageCode   STRING  NULLABLE
```

If I use the jackson `ObjectMapper`, the JSON gets parsed but it doesn't get inserted to the BigQuery because in the JSON the `display` is only a record but in the BigQuery it is a list of records, so there seems to be a mismatch and I am unable to insert such custom fields.

Please provide any solutions to tackle this problem, in short whereever in the JSON from the link above provided there is "en", I am facing this issue.

Any help is appreciated.

```
ObjectMapper objectmapper = new ObjectMapper();  
objectmapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRITE_NULL_MAP_VALUES, false); 
objectmapper.setSerializationInclusion(Include.NON_NULL);
ashMap<String, Object> tempResult = objectmapper.readValue(stageJson, HashMap.class);
```

Comment: There's `ashMap` in your code, propably you mean `HashMap`

Comment: Yes I am trying to convert the json into a hashmap (i.e a key value pair) as per the schema

Comment: Like if the object mapper converts the verb to something like verb={id=http://id.tincanapi.com/verb/viewed ,display={en=viewed} }
 and i would like to convert it to verb={id=http://id.tincanapi.com/verb/viewed ,display=[{languageCode=en, stringValue=viewed}] }

Answer (score 0):

The `display` node is also a record in BigQuery. Here is how the schema must be set:

```
[
 {
   "name": "verb",
   "type": "RECORD",
   "mode": "NULLABLE",
   "fields": [
       {
         "name": "id",
         "type": "STRING",
         "mode": "NULLABLE"
       },
       {
         "name": "display",
         "type": "RECORD",
         "mode": "REPEATED",
         "fields": [
            {
              "name": "enUS",
              "type": "STRING",
              "mode": "NULLABLE"
            }
         ]
       }
    ]
 }
]
```

the problem with your `verb` example is the absence of square brackets containing the field; besides, there is another issue with the hyphen "-" in `en-US`: as field names can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores. it must be set to e.g. `enUS`.

here is the schema as displayed in the UI if your `verb` example (after `enUs` correction) is imported  [using schema auto-detection](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schema-detect):

```
verb                RECORD  NULLABLE    
verb.display        RECORD  NULLABLE    
verb.display.enUS   STRING  NULLABLE    
verb.id             STRING  NULLABLE
```

Types are correct, however `display` mode is detected as `NULLABLE`, because there are no `[ ]`.

as BigQuery JSON import format is newline delimited, then this import must be in this format:

```
{"verb":{"id":"http://adlnet.gov/expapi/verbs/failed","display":[{"enUS":"failed"}]}}
```

then `display` mode is detected as `REPEATED`.

once have your schema sorted and have a well-formed and valid JSON file, then simply [use the BigQuery Java API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/loading-data-local#loading_data_from_a_local_data_source) to upload it, without the need of a complex flow and a third-party library to serialize JSON beforehand.

Source:

[Specifying a Schema](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/schemas)

[Specifying nested and repeated columns](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/nested-repeated)

Comment: 10 (ten) updates within last 1 hour?! Noone is rushing you - can you please focus and make one final update so it is not bombarding SO UI! ;o)

Comment: I'm rewording only, this is for the better, and I'm actually done now. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: i know / I see - just wanted to make sure that you are realizing - each and every your update is popping up in UI - not the best way to do such updates  - i usually do all edits locally and then do update - just wanted to mention o)

Comment: @alp actually I in no way can change the source json schema structure or the big query schema. I will just have to map it both in the same way